# How to resolve unallocated disk/drive problem in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gparted, disk, drive

How to fix the unallocated space issue on the selected drive on my Ubuntu 20.04?
Plese refer to this GParted screenshot:

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Something is only an issue when it causes a problem. What is the problem in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, seems to be the case this disk /dev/sda, as this is the medium we are talking about, was formerly a Windows 10 OS installation.

So, to be honest, best would be to save the data and make a fresh Linux installation.

The other way round you may create a partition called /dev/sda3 as an additional primary partition and use a mount like /backup or /additional in order to use it for anything.
I do not know, for what reason you created that many different partitions, as, there is usually no use for.

With Gparted, you are able to move partition spaces, delete the start and endpoint of partitions and even delete, create partitions.
Get familiar with it, but before that, make a backup of your data to another storage device.